# How to share the global scss file among different libraries in angular 7?

Tags: angular7

Following is my project structure -

```
./projects
  my-library-1
  my-library-2
  my-library-3
  .
  .
  styles.scss /* I need to apply this global scss to all the above libraries */

src/
  app/
      app.module.ts
  main.ts
  index.scss
  index.html

README.md
```

Is there any way to apply that scss file globally to all the libraries in the project folder rather than importing the scss file manually in all the libraries?

If any please help me with the solution.

Thank you